# QGIS Atlas: Only Show Selected Feature

Tags: qgis, line, atlas

I have 20 lines on one layer, and many of them overlap like a grid.

I have currently used the following:

```
[%'ROUTE #' || CASE WHEN $id = $atlasfeatureid THEN "Route #" END%]
```

When I use the atlas function to zoom to a specific line, it will still show the other lines within the zoom extent.

I only want the line that the atlas function is zooming to to be visible, but still allow me to flick through all 20 lines/atlas pages.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: That question is similar to this one [QGIS Atlas: Only Show Selected Feature](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199496/print-a-centered-map-from-a-qgis-project-for-each-point-in-a-shapefile/199867?noredirect=1#comment319926_199867) Does that answer your question?

Comment: Look here [How to generate multiple maps where one highlighted attribute changes?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221788/how-to-generate-multiple-maps-where-one-highlighted-attribute-changes). For hiding other features just change symbology from grey to some with "no fill" or transparent, or use only symbology as @iant mention in his answer (`$id = @atlasfeatureid`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Rule-based` style with the filter `$id = @atlasfeatureid` to hide the features that you are not interested in.

[image]

Comment: please note that @ atlasfeatureid is now  @ atlas_featureid