# Show only polygon of interest in Atlas, QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, atlas

I'm using Atlas Generation in QGIS to produce a sequence of maps based on the features of a polygons shapefile. Atlas works very well for this purpose but, even though it does iterate on the features (polygons) of the shapefile, more than one polygon may be visible. Is there a way to have only the polygon of interest active when using the atlas.

[image]

Comment: You want a Mask see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u29yGSQhX2g

Comment: Try the expression from this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-filter-features-in-other-layers-of-a-qgis-atlas