# Hiding polygons outside of current atlas feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas, masking

[image: Current atlas feature shown centre, other atlas features seen nearby (e.g. to the east)]

Within the above image, I would like to ideally hide the polygons outside the current atlas feature (some to the east and also to the west - these are part of other atlas features)

They are currently masked which helps, but it would better if they could be hidden entirely.

I still want the MasterMap to show through, so I cannot just increase the strength of the mask (unless I can do that and exclude the MasterMap from the mask somehow?).

This is being created within QGIS 2.18.17 in a map composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you call the MasterMap is your original parcel map and you have different polygon entities for the parcels you want to colorize, everything can be done with styling.

Take a look at this [question/answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260392/show-only-features-within-current-atlas-feature?rq=1). It has the basic idea of a method that works. Setting a rule-based symbology on the layer you want to selectively hide, build a rule like this:

```
within($geometry, @atlas_geometry)
```

Just make sure the layer used as atlas features is the one that circumscribes your interest zones.

Comment: I've been looking for that for a long time since the Mask puglin doesn't work properly on QGIS 3. Thanks a lot.