# QGIS filter Atlas with intersecting geometries

Tags: qgis, geometry, atlas

At [Show only features within current Atlas feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260392) I learned a valuable way of using Atlas. I need to move it a step further but lack the skill.

How do I filter the atlas using geometry of other layers?

I don’t know how to reference a layer in the command line. If I use this:

> intersects( $geometry , @atlas_geometry )

Then it only works for the current geometry. But the current geometry is from the atlas layer, I need to use a different layer geometry that I need to reference (I know this must be possible, but dont know how to do it). What I want to do is to filter the atlas, so that only areal units that have certain points in them are shown and exported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For my understanding, you want to apply a filter to your atlas layer based on other layer geometry.

In the layout control panel, you can set a filter applied on your atlas layer to get atlas produced only for some feature of your atlas layer. Just click in the epsilon icon.

[image]

The formula will be really simple with the function `overlay_intersects()` (it is present **since QGIS 3.16 version**).

```
overlay_intersects( 'New_scratch_layer_d419445a_e71d_44d4_b0ca_e1a6dbb86b17')
```

Replace `'New_scratch_layer_d419445a_e71d_44d4_b0ca_e1a6dbb86b17'` with your layer name or id. You could access it with the expression toolbox, just double click in the layer name you want to use.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is so simple, I feel a bit dumb. Thanks.

Comment: It is really new function so normal not to know it.

Answer (score 4):

In older versions than QGIS 3.16 you can use `aggregate()` to test the intersection against a whole layer.

As "Filter with" argument in the atlas properties use: `intersects(aggregate('LayerName','collect',$geometry), @atlas_geometry)`

You can also add a filter to the `aggregate()` function, to only use parts of the layer, for example: `intersects(aggregate('LayerName','collect',$geometry,filter:=$id<>11), @atlas_geometry)`

[image]

Comment: Cool way to do it, thank you.