# Filtering a map in print composer

Tags: print-composer, filter, feature-layer

Is it possible to filter a map's layer inside Print Composer, like it is possible to filter a layer in Qgis main window?

I have a layer with several points, and I'd like to create several layouts and in each of them have one map displaying only one of those points (filtered by a specific attribute in the attribute table).

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-filter-features-in-other-layers-of-a-qgis-atlas#173443

Comment: Thank you! I can use an atlas with a rule to control visibility according to current atlas feature being evaluated. Only issue is that in this way the points are not visible in the main qgis windows, but I can switch style if I need to see them.