# QGIS rule based symbology for rasters in Atlas?

Tags: raster, symbology, qgis-3, rule-based, atlas-generator

I'm making species distribution maps and have got the Atlas working perfectly using a polygon layer to show the quarter degree grid cells for species observation records. I have ~ 250 species.

The problem is that I have for most species a predicted ecological niche model (raster) which I would also like to display on the map and I can't find a way to do this using the Atlas functionality.

There's a very helpful post showing how to use rule based symbology for another polygon file but not for rasters ([Filtering features in other layers of QGIS Atlas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-filter-features-in-other-layers-of-a-qgis-atlas?newreg=2d1b03b083c346f598a5303ae58712d6))

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Came across a similar problem, a possible and simple workaround is to convert your raster into a vector using "Raster pixels to polygon" which is a QGIS native algorithm.

Then, use a join operation to link your coverage layer with the created vector layer in the previous step.

Then, use the same rule-based styling as suggested on the link that you provided.