# QGIS Atlas filter with category

Tags: qgis, atlas

I want to create a QGIS Atlas on a point of interest dataset with categorical attribute `poi_type`.
The atlas should have a page for each type (e.g. stadium, hospital, etc.).

I can't find the right filter to set in the `filter with` field. QGIS keeps cycling over each feature, as opposed to cycling over each unique value of `poi_type`. Any tip?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a separate table with one entry per poi_type.  Then you can use that as coveragelayer to loop through.  More info on this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287540/7849