# How to generate multiple maps for each feature using same scale and displaying only the one feature?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2, atlas

I am using QGIS 2.18.

I've got a layer consisting of 40+ features (lines of movement per day). And I'd like to automatically create maps that always show exactly the same area. But the difference is that I want to show only one feature per map (one day). Is that possible?

I already tried the atlas functionality, but it doesn't provide displaying only one feature and leaving out the remaining, right?

Comment: Did you read that (part 1) https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/series-de-mapas-com-formatos-multiplos-em-qgis-2-6-parte-1-multiple-format-map-series-using-qgis-2-6-part-1/ and (part 2) https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/multiple-format-map-series-using-qgis-2-6-part-2/

Comment: I did now, it's about the atlas usage to get different formats or different shown areas. But in my case, both should be fix, only the content (displayed features) should vary.

Comment: That' why it's not an answer, the goal was to give you exemple of how to make expression relative to the atlas page being displayed so you could filter your data

Comment: If you read through other questions with the [atlas] tag, you'll find other examples of using the variables `$atlasgeometry` and `$atlasfeature` to control which features are displayed in each atlas page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In print composer, set up an atlas using the desired layer as the atlas coverage layer. Choose a field for the page name.

In the map canvas, turn on rule-based symbology for the layer. Add a single rule with this filter:

> "fieldname" =  @atlas_pagename

The syntax provided should work in QGIS 2.18 and 3.x. If you're using a different version, use the syntax shown in the expression builder in your version of the program.

Once you enable this symbology, the layer will disappear from the map canvas. It will only display when have the atlas preview open.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks a lot! 
In addition i'll add a link to a similar solution (as you wrote in your comment) for further Information: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-filter-features-in-other-layers-of-a-qgis-atlas