# Rule-Based: filter test is not working on QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I made one Atlas Map based on this exercise (https://anitagraser.com/2016/10/15/qgis-atlas-tutorial-material-design/) and I had good results working with QGIS 2.18.

But when I use QGIS 3.4 I can not get the same results.

As you can see in this picture bellow in **QGIS 2.18** I have this notification when I run the filter test:

[image]

This is what happens when I run the same filter code in **QGIS 3.4:**

[image]

> Filter expression parsing error:
>
> $atlasfeatureid function is not known
>
> $map function is not known

So in this case - What do I need to do?

Comment: Have you seen this thread [Filtering features in other layers of QGIS Atlas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/filtering-features-in-other-layers-of-qgis-atlas)

Answer (score 3):

Tutorial might be for earlier version of QGIS, wrong syntax is used. The right syntax (in QGIS 3.4) is:

1st rule - **$id=@atlas_featurenumber AND @map_id='ZOOM'**

2nd rule - **@map_id='GENERAL'**

3th rule - **$id= @atlas_featurenumber  AND @map_id='GENERAL'**

You can use search in Expression string builder to get the right syntax if not sure about it:

[image]

Comment: +1 for using the Expression builder to help with syntax.