# Styles when using Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas

I'm trying to create 19 maps representing a highway construction. I need each map to show only the featured geometry and a  its classification
I´ve tried using expressions like this

*"situ_Pista Nova" = 'Executado' AND @atlas_featureNUMBER = "Atlas_id"*

The Atlas_id is a new column created to match the atlas_featurenumber. The atlas coverage layer is not the same as the layer I want to show

but every feature just falls and the rule else.

[image: what i'm getting/what I want]

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/filtering-features-in-other-layers-of-qgis-atlas?rq=1

Comment: where are you using that expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this result using Rules styling with expression  `"atlas_id" =  @atlas_pagename`, and using "atlas_id" field as name of page of atlas.

[image]

[image]

[image]