# Style layer in QGIS according to class-column and create automated map based on date-column

Tags: qgis, style, spatio-temporal-data

I have a layer coming from this [GeoJSON](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XFtKxIYxiRaTRtsoeKn-Hpy-EbAgv7jJ/view?usp=sharing)

It looks like this:

[image]

I want to style the layer (give colors to the polygons) in a categorized way. And each class should always (over all dates) have the same color. However I also want to make a map for each date. I see two options on how to do that, yet I do not know if any of them works:

1. The Temporal option: The problem here is that I can't use the temporal controller to build maps in the print layout with legends, exports as svg...
2. Using the Atlas. However (looking at this answer: [Filtering features in other layers of QGIS Atlas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/filtering-features-in-other-layers-of-qgis-atlas)) I am not sure if I can use a categorized style combined with a rule-based style in order to ensure that all same classes are styled the same way but only shown for the current date. If I use the date as converage layer in the qgis atlas

Is there any other, better way of achieving this without creating as many print comoposer maps as there are unique dates in the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with an Atlas:

Create a Virtual layer wityh no geometry, that will hold the unique dates from your 'test' layer. Let's call it `datelist`, we will use it as an Atlas input.

[image]

In the layouts, set the Atlas to use `datelist` as coverage layer, with `pagename`set to the `date`field:

[image]

Now, edit the rule based Style as mentioned in the link you provided:

[image]

Export the Layout as multi-page PDF:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot!!:) That already helps a lot! do you have any idea on how I could achieve the same without creating an additional layer?

Comment: I don't see any clear option. You might be able to use the original layer itself for the Atlas, but you will end-up with multiple outputs for every feature/date...

Comment: thanks a lot again!:) That really helped:)