# Connecting additional layers to coverage layer using QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas

My coverage layer is streets and I want to have only certain objects shown on my additional layer according to which street is shown.  The QGIS Atlas page name is the name of the street which also appears in the attributes table of my additional layer.

Is there a way to simply have this connected so that i can export my desired results automatically?

I have multiple objects in the additional layer and they do not intersect geographically with the coverage layer.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve (even if it looks like it is perfectly feasible). Provide more details/screenshots and you should get an answer

Comment: Do this help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/filtering-features-in-other-layers-of-qgis-atlas

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with a rule based renderer for your additional layer with a rule like this one:

```
 "fk" = attribute(@atlas_feature,'name')
```

where "fk" is a field in your additional layer with the foreign key to your street layer (the atlas feature layer).

[image]

When you enter the rule, all the features from your additional layer will disapear because the @atlas_feature will not be evaluated in the map view.

[image]

finally within the atlas the expression can be evaluated and only the features with the same name in the foreign key field will be shown.

[image]