# Expression to filter objects outside of an atlas in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-atlas

I have a filter on a layer

```
"LOCALITY" != 'Queenton'
```

It just covers up the area outside of the AOI.

I want to connect this to the atlas so that this 'masking' happens as the Atlas moves between Localities.

Is there a way to do something like
`"LOCALITY" != '@Atlas'` ?

I also tried

```
"LOCALITY" != '$feature'
```

I am using the new Clipping in QGIS 3.16 as suggested in [Filtering features in other layers of QGIS Atlas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/filtering-features-in-other-layers-of-qgis-atlas) to clip some unwanted features but I want the roads, rivers and protected areas (for example) to show but be covered by a translucent grey polygon as below...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try:

```
"LOCALITY" != @atlas_feature
```

or

```
attribute(@atlas_feature, 'LOCALITY')
```

You have to check which one will better suit to your needs.

Comment: For both I get an error like the following. This is in the Filter expression. ` - An error occurred when executing the query.
The data provider said:
OGR[3] error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected $undefined. Occurred around :
"LOCALITY" != @atlas_feature
              ^`

Comment: You need to use it in rule-based styling rather than in filtering of features.

Comment: I just tried both options and there's no error but when I cycle through the maps, I see no difference. Is it possible to use something similar in the filter?

Comment: Worked it out in the end. Had to use `"LOCALITY" not in (attribute(@atlas_feature, 'LOCALITY'))` with an else statement that had no symbology. Then in the Atlas clip I had to exclude this layer from clipping.