# Differentiate the symbology within a polygon from another layer in QGIS outside of the atlas feature

Tags: qgis, atlas

In an atlas I want some features that are outside the AOI to display muted (in grey).

I am getting close to what I want by

a. Creating a duplicate of the layer and changing the color to grey in this mask layer

b. Clipping the primary layer in the atlas

It works fine for the symbology but the labels are duplicated sometimes.

**So is there a way to filter the 'mask' layer by the 'locality'?**

[image]

Yellow duplication of town names and green duplication of roads.

The locality mask is achieved by
[image]

The features I want to clip the inside of (i.e not display the features within the @atlas_feature) do not have a locality attribute (so I can't use [Filtering features in other layers of QGIS Atlas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/filtering-features-in-other-layers-of-qgis-atlas)) and so I would like to do something like

```
within ($geometry, geometry(get_feature('Locality','LOCALITY','attribute(@atlas_feature, 'LOCALITY')')))
```

Can this be done at the filter level on the dataset or does it need to be done on both rule based labeling and symbology?